# Floor of skybox is rotated 180 degrees in THREE.js

Tags: three.js

I am working on a game in three.js (but it is my first) and I am making a skybox, all of the images are perfect except for the one on the bottom is flipped 180 degrees.

I've tried rotating the image in  mac os preview but that didn't change anything, and I can't find any help online.

here is my code

[image: picture of skybox]

//cube2 means skybox
// this is all the code for my skybox (using three.js)

var cubeMaterials =
    [

```
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: new THREE.TextureLoader( ).load( 'Images/skybox/PositiveX.png' ), side: THREE.DoubleSide } ), // Right side

  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: new THREE.TextureLoader( ).load( 'Images/skybox/NegativeX.png' ), side: THREE.DoubleSide } ), // Left side

  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: new THREE.TextureLoader( ).load( 'Images/skybox/NegativeY.png' ), side: THREE.DoubleSide } ), // Top side

  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: new THREE.TextureLoader( ).load( 'Images/skybox/PositiveY.png' ), side: THREE.DoubleSide} ), // Bottom side

  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: new THREE.TextureLoader( ).load( 'Images/skybox/PositiveZ.png' ), side: THREE.DoubleSide } ), // Front side

  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: new THREE.TextureLoader( ).load( 'Images/skybox/NegativeZ.png' ), side: THREE.DoubleSide } ) // Back side

];
// Create a MeshFaceMaterial, which allows the cube to have different materials on each face


var geometry2 = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 100000, 100000, 100000 );

var cube2 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry2, cubeMaterials );

scene.add( cube2 );
```

Answer (score 2):

There are much easier ways to use a skybox in three.js

Use the `CubeTextureLoader` and just assign the result to the `scene.background` like this

```
const loader = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader();
const texture = loader.load([
  'path/to/pos-x.jpg',
  'path/to/neg-x.jpg',
  'path/to/pos-y.jpg',
  'path/to/neg-y.jpg',
  'path/to/pos-z.jpg',
  'path/to/neg-z.jpg',
]);
scene.background = texture;
```

Example

```js
'use strict';

/* global THREE */

function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas
  });

  const fov = 75;
  const aspect = 2; // the canvas default
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 100;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.z = 2;

  const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, canvas);
  controls.target.set(0, 0, 0);
  controls.update();

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();

  {
    const loader = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader();
    const texture = loader.load([
      'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/images/cubemaps/computer-history-museum/pos-x.jpg',
      'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/images/cubemaps/computer-history-museum/neg-x.jpg',
      'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/images/cubemaps/computer-history-museum/pos-y.jpg',
      'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/images/cubemaps/computer-history-museum/neg-y.jpg',
      'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/images/cubemaps/computer-history-museum/pos-z.jpg',
      'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/images/cubemaps/computer-history-museum/neg-z.jpg',
    ]);
    scene.background = texture;
  }

  function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    const width = canvas.clientWidth;
    const height = canvas.clientHeight;
    const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
    if (needResize) {
      renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    }
    return needResize;
  }

  function render(time) {

    if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
      const canvas = renderer.domElement;
      camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

main();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#c {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas tabstop="1" id="c"></canvas>

<script src="https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r103/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r103/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

from [here](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-backgrounds.html)

Answer (score 0):

In order to rotate a texture, you can set `texture.rotation` to a specific value rotation.

Check [documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/Texture.rotation) for more information on that.

```
let texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'filepath' );
texture.center.set( 0.5, 0.5 ) // move rotation point to the center of the texture
texture.rotation = Math.PI; // rotates around center axis by 180 degrees.
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8czhmytL/